# Walls closing in

Tags: meaning, idioms

> An old couple who are my friends, are so lonely that the walls are closing in/on them.

Is my phrase correct to say that they start to behave oddly?

Comment: They "*feel* the walls closing in" (or "feel like the walls are closing in").  But this does not directly imply "odd" behavior, merely a state of mind of being "trapped", or perhaps "suffocating".

Comment: If they feel the walls closing in, they are, or they soon will, behave oddly.  They need help.

Comment: @ab2 - Actually, they may be trapped in a trash compactor.

Comment: Have you thought about asking on our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: @Old Bunny They need SE.  They will get addicded to one of he sites, and never notice the walls.

Comment: @AlejandroBarocio  Are you asking if it Is your place to tell them that they are behaving oddly?  You could invite them out for coffee and talk to them.  One has to play such things by ear, and avoid getting too involved, but even so there must be social agencies or social clubs to which you could direct them.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the phrase [Stir Crazy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stir_crazy_(condition)). This generally refers to someone who's going a bit nutty due to prolonged loneliness or incarceration.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that the term "feeling the walls closing in" is anxiety. I has having an episode when I had a major presentation, a paper, a test, another paper, 4 classes (everything to this point was due the next day), an exam the next day, paper #3, and a dying grandmother. I'm in college BTW, but the feeling described above is apart of an anxiety attack.